# ML: Is it possible to create a list of structures in SML?

Tags: list, structure, sml, ml

I am a beginner to ML/Haskell and I am trying to create a list of structures. 
Actually, I am developing a web application in [Urweb](http://www.impredicative.com/ur/) (functional web programming language, a lot of features from ML and Haskell.) I am trying to create an interface to [Tinymce](https://www.tinymce.com) (open source rich text editor, and it consists of all the plugin such as print, link). So to manage all plugins, I am composing in the form of structure and I need one data structure to hold all the structures (Plugins in my case) and at the end stage in can be used to initialize my editor.

For example:

```
val plugins = [print, link, img];
```

and elements inside list `plugins` such as `print` is a structure:

```
structure print = struct
  type t = string
  .
  .
end
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can't put structures in lists at all in SML; they are part of the _module language,_ not the _core language_ which contains values which can be manipulated. That said, I would reiterate that we need to know what your end goal is here before we can help.

Comment: @jeevjyot It sounds like you probably want functors rather, for instance see the little "plugin" contained in the link, since the results of the functors share the same types, they *can* be contained in a list. http://www.catonmat.net/blog/on-functors/

Comment: oh right, that sounds like an idea. So all functos would return the structure and thats how they share the same type, right? please correct me if am wrong. thanks for the link. @matt

Comment: @jeevjyotsinghchhabda right, share the same input/output types, but the functions can still have a "closure" over their individual structure.

Comment: @matt Right, make sense. thanks so much, I'll try to implement that. thanks again

Comment: @matt, i am trying to create a list of functors, i am getting error. This is my sig  `signature init = sig
  val plugin : functor list;
 end; ` what would be the correct syntax? thanks

Comment: @jeevjyotsinghchhabda I went ahead and tried to come up with an answer, even though it isn't quite what you originally asked, seemed easier than continuing in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general answer is that No you cannot create a list of
structures, the same is true as well of signatures, and functors

however; if your plugin system is built in a way in which the entry types, and exit types of each plugin are the same across all plugins, you can build a kind of closure to a structure and embed that into a function.

you can then use functors, to build up the functions of your plugin system

We start out with the interface of each "plugin".

```
signature DANCER =
sig
    type t;

    val dancer : t
    val tired : t -> bool
    val dance : t -> t;
end
```

Followed by the interface through which our application interacts with the plugin.

```
datatype exhaustion = Exhausted;

signature DANCING_MANIA =
sig
  val dance : unit -> exhaustion;
end
```

The implementation of the above DANCING_MANIA signature,
accepts a DANCER, and hides the differences between plugins/structures

```
functor Dancer (D : DANCER) : DANCING_MANIA =
struct

  fun dance() =
    let fun until_exhaustion (dancer) =
         if not (D.tired dancer)
            then until_exhaustion(D.dance(dancer))
            else Exhausted;
     in until_exhaustion(D.dancer) end
end
```

Finally we can implement some plugins, and throw them in a list.

```
structure Tony :> DANCER =
struct
  type t = int;

  val dancer = 5;

  fun tired x = x <= 0;
  fun dance x = (print "tony dance!\n"; x - 1);
end

structure Annette :> DANCER =
struct
  type t = real;

  val dancer = 1.0;

  fun tired x = x <= 0.0;
  fun dance x = (print "annette dance!\n"; x - 0.2);
end
structure TonyDance = Dancer(Tony);
structure AnnetteDance = Dancer(Annette);

val dancers = [TonyDance.dance, AnnetteDance.dance];

fun danceOff (x::xs) = let val _ = x(); in danceOff(xs) end
  | danceOff ([]) = ();
val _ = danceOff(dancers);
```

So, the idea is that while you cannot create a list of structures,
you can create a list of things, that each contain a different structure,
as long as the exposed types are uniform.

Comment: Thanks, @matt for the detailed explanation. I would share once the project is completed.